# How to use OpenStreetMap in native android app development

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

Hello I have the default android " Dummy Content " native app build in my android phone.. now I need to use the open street map applicaiton and intergrate it into this build with a GPS location ..

I could not find any infos in google search.. can any one help me with the links or suggestions?

Also which is better and ease of doing? Google maps or open streep maps in Android Devices...

please let me know.

Comment: Head over to Open street map's  site and have a read up. Thank me later.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to show map content you can do it with Google Maps (already in Android libraries), or you can use different map data (e.g. OpenStreetMap). 
There are two known communities amongst others, who developed a Android Library for OpenStreetMap data maps:

1. http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/
2. https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/

At today, the Google's Google Map View is the most easy to use API. Unfortunetly it's commercial in some points. For example, you are not allowed to develop an application showing google map content in combination with turn-by-turn guidance (cf. Google Maps Terms of Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en ). In opposite, OSMDroid is free to use for everything.

There are many tutorials in the web, which teach step by step how to show the GPS location of the device on a maps content in your application. Some of them are:

Google Maps: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

OSMDroid: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/05/display-current-location-marker-on.html

**EDIT:** 
I received some question about if a turn-by-turn guidance navigation app is possible to implement (and publish). The answer is yes. 
On a license view, you must not use googlemaps, but e.g. OSMDroid is fine here.

I have done this myself once using OSMDroid as a mapview library and OSMDroidBonusPack as Routing, Geocoding and reverseGeocoding library (the bonuspack has several more features, see all at [the git repository](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Features)

I wanted to provide another link to existing navigation apps implemented by using OSMDroid, but it seems they are no longer maintained for updates.

Comment: @MojinoMS The link you provided for OSMDroid: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/05/display-current-location-marker-on.html
seems to be from the middle.. Coudld you do it form the step 1. After the default Android App setup?

Comment: there are some more lessons in that tutorial, u can click to the previous one at the top of the page and go to the next one at the bottom of it. Here is the link for the first lesson: http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/05/simple-example-use-osmdroid-and-slf4j.html

Comment: +1 for pointing out the license limitations which are normally not that well known!

Comment: @MojioMS: Can you tell is there turn-by-turn voice guidance is possible to develop with OSMDroid? and if you have any related useful link please share them here.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni: I added it in the answer after edit

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at AnyMaps, it allows you to use OpenStreetMap as one of the options while having API which is close to Google Maps:
https://github.com/car2go/AnyMaps

Comment: Can you please tell me the latest version of anyMaps? I'm not getting the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/zsoltk/overpasser. It's a Java library to ease working with the Overpass API.

1. It generates the Overpass query string for you
2. It comes with a Retrofit adapter
3. It has an Android sample showing how to put them all together and show your OpenStreetMap data on Google Maps