# How to include GeoJson using open street map in android?

Tags: android, gps, geojson, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I'm using Open Street Map, and I need to save my added points inside a GeoJson so that I can then visualize these points according to the saved coordinates, time, and open within an analyzer of that type of file.

At the first moment, I do not have much data. I only have code using Open Street Map, which still needs some changes.

```
package br.com.josileudorodrigues.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cocoahero.android.geojson.GeoJSON;

import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.KmlDocument;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.NominatimPOIProvider;
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.location.POI;
import org.osmdroid.config.Configuration;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapEventsReceiver;
import org.osmdroid.events.MapListener;
import org.osmdroid.events.ScrollEvent;
import org.osmdroid.events.ZoomEvent;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.Projection;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.FolderOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MapEventsOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.MinimapOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Overlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.OverlayItem;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.PathOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.CompassOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.compass.InternalCompassOrientationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.InfoWindow;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.infowindow.MarkerInfoWindow;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.GpsMyLocationProvider;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.mylocation.MyLocationNewOverlay;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MapEventsReceiver, LocationListener {

    private static final int PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA =1 ;

    private MapView osm;
    private MapController mc;
    private CompassOverlay mCompassOverlay;
    private MyLocationNewOverlay mLocationOverlay;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private PathOverlay po;
    private KmlDocument kmlDocument;


    ArrayList<OverlayItem> overlayItemArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //onde mostra a imagem do mapa
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Essa é para poder utilizar as permissões
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapaId);
        osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        osm.setUseDataConnection(true);
        osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        osm.setClickable(true);
        osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] permissoes = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
                requestPermissions(permissoes, PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA);
            }
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] permissoes = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissoes, PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA);
            }
        }

        osm.setMapListener(new MapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onScroll ()");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onZoom ()");
                return false;
            }
        });



        mc = (MapController) osm.getController();
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(-5.1251, -38.3640);
        mc.setZoom(14);
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);


     /*   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //TODO: Consider calling

            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);*/

        MapEventsOverlay mapEventsOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(this, this);
        osm.getOverlays().add(0, mapEventsOverlay);

        // Aqui adiciona a escala do mapa
        ScaleBarOverlay scaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(osm);
        osm.getOverlays().add(scaleBarOverlay);

        kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    //    kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(geoJsonString);

        /*this.mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(ctx),osm);
        this.mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        osm.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);*/

        this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(this), osm);
        this.mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
        osm.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA: {
                // Se a solicitação de permissão foi cancelada o array vem vazio.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permissão cedida, recria a activity para carregar o mapa, só será executado uma vez
                    this.recreate();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void addMarker(final GeoPoint center) {
        final Marker marker = new Marker(osm);
        marker.setPosition(center);
        marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
        marker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_mapa));
        marker.setDraggable(true);

        marker.setTitle("DADOS");
        marker.setSnippet(center.getLatitude()+ "," + center.getLongitude());
        marker.setSubDescription("subDescription Marker");

        marker.setInfoWindow(new CustomMarkerInfoWindow(osm));
        marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, marker.ANCHOR_TOP);


        marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m, MapView mapView) {
                Log.i("Script","onMarkerClick");
                m.showInfoWindow();
                InfoWindow.getOpenedInfoWindowsOn(osm);
                return true;
            }
        });

        marker.setOnMarkerDragListener(new Marker.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDragStart()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDragEnd()");

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                Log.i("Script", "onMarkerDrag()");
            }
        });

      //  osm.getOverlays().clear();
        osm.getOverlays().add(new MapOverlay(this));
        osm.getOverlays().add(marker);
        osm.invalidate();


    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //this will refresh the osmdroid configuration on resuming.
        //if you make changes to the configuration, use
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Configuration.getInstance().load(this, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this));
        osm.onResume(); //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        //this will refresh the osmdroid configuration on resuming.
        //if you make changes to the configuration, use
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Configuration.getInstance().save(this, prefs);
        osm.onPause();  //needed for compass, my location overlays, v6.0.0 and up
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
        public MapOverlay(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas c, MapView osmv, boolean shadow) {

        }

        // aqui é onde movimenta o cursor do mapa
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent me, MapView mv) {
            Projection p = osm.getProjection();
            GeoPoint gp = (GeoPoint) p.fromPixels((int) me.getX(), (int) me.getY());
            addMarker(gp);

            return (true); // se false ---> vai travar o mapa
        }
    }

    // Aqui quando eu pressionar em uma determinada parte do mapa ele
    // irá  mostrar as minhas cordenadas
    @Override
    public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Coordenadas:\nLatitude: ("+p.getLatitude() +"\nLongitude: " +
                ""+p.getLongitude()+")" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       // InfoWindow.closeAllInfoWindowsOn(osm); //Clicando em qualquer canto da tela, fecha o infowindow
        return (true);
    }

    //Aqui eu adiciono uma marcação se eu pressionar a tela
    @Override
    public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
       // addMarker(p);
        return true;
    }

    // InfoWindow
    public class CustomMarkerInfoWindow extends MarkerInfoWindow {

        public CustomMarkerInfoWindow(MapView mapView) {
            super(R.layout.bonuspack_bubble,mapView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(Object item){

            Marker m = (Marker) item;

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_image);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_moreinfo);

            TextView snippet = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_title);
            snippet.setText(m.getTitle());

            TextView coordenada = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id. coordenadas);
            coordenada.setText(m.getSnippet());

            Button bt = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_buttom);
            bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Salvo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

The results I got trying to implement geojson were not satisfactory. I saw several tutorials, but none explained whether or not I had to implement a `public void` method, if I would have to put it inside the `onCreate` method, or if I would have to create one Java file.

How can I do this?

Comment: refer to this topic it's helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518090/how-to-use-openstreetmap-in-native-android-app-development/21518582

Answer (score 1):

You should find most of what you need in [OSMBonusPack GeoJSON features](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_4). 
But this is assuming you have the right level of skills about Java and Android development.